# Retrieving a message from a cryptocurrency daemon

Tags: php, php5, laravel, cryptocurrency

The objective of this piece of code is to get a message from a cryptocurrency daemon through RPC and extract the transactions object to pass it to the view. Is there a simpler / less ugly way of doing this?

```
$transaction_pool = json_decode($rpc->getTransactionPool(), false);

if(isset($transaction_pool->transactions)){
    $transaction_pool = $transaction_pool->transactions;
}else{
    $transaction_pool = (object)NULL;
}
```

View partial:

```
@forelse ($transaction_pool as $transaction)
<?php $transaction_json = json_decode($transaction->tx_json); ?>
    <div class="row show-grid top-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7">{{ $transaction->id_hash }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-5 pull-right">
        @if ($transaction_json->version == 2)
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-6"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbsp;confidential</div>
        @else
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-6">@coin($transaction_json->amount)</div>
        @endif
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-6">@coin($transaction->fee)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @empty
    <div class="row show-grid top-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">No transactions</div>
    </div>
@endforelse
```

```
<div class="panel-heading large">
    Transactions ({{ count($transaction_pool) }})
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please try to write a title that summarizes what your code does; as it is the title is quite generic and could apply to many other questions.

Comment: Yes much better!

Comment: Can you give examples of  JSON returned from rpc for empty and not empty cases?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the point where you cast `null` to `object`.

I'm not sure what are you trying to achive,
but you can always make if 'less ugly'.

```
$transcations_pool = json_decode($rpc->getTransactionPool(), false);   
$transactions_pool = isset($transactions_pool->transactions) ? 
                         $transaction_pool->transactions : 
                         (object) null;
```

Also i would move `div .show-grid` to separate file and load it like this:

```
@include('path/to/file', [ 'transaction_json' => json_decode($transaction->tx_json) ])
```

Or you can implement special method like `$transaction->decodeTxJson()` to handle this decoding in `$transaction class`.

Comment: Ternary operators is a big NO here.

Comment: To be honest this is way more readable to me. Three lines to show `condition`, `true section` and `false section`. But i understand some people find these as you called "big NO".

Comment: The object casting needs to be entirely removed. There are many clean approaches to do that.

Comment: @rk-dev.net Righto. I kinda forgot to add the crucial part of the code. I need to count() the result of the json_decode. Since it is not Countable it returns 1 even if it is empty. Edited the question. Thanks!